# error message: clientside validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What is the meaning of the following error message?How can I use the EnableClienTValidation()?

> Error 3 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'EnableClientValidation' and no extension method 'EnableClientValidation' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\Dev\DEV\test3\Code\MvcUI\Views\Customer\Create.aspx 11 13 MvcUI

I have reference the following:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js" )%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Html.EnableClientValidation()` helper is [available on ASP.NET MVC 2.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx). Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.0.  How can I include 2.0?

Comment: <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

Comment: Here's a tutorial explaining how to migrate an ASP.NET MVC 1.0 application to 2.0 : http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet-mvc2-upgrade-notes/